# AWS S3 > Life Cycle Policy > to delete S3 bucket profiles not utilised over 3 months?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking into possibility to setup a policy to delete the profiles within S3 bucket that have not been used over 3+ months.  Is that possible and where would I setup?

Would appreciate your guidance.

Comment: If you're going to use AWS you really need to do some training. It's a complex enterprise system. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html

Comment: any links to basic start for S3 and life cycle? I understand AWS is a huge monster and complex as you say ...

Comment: The link I posted above is the best start. If you don't understand it you can google for an "aws s3 lifecycle tutorial"